# use concat or replace for values in the middle SQL / Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

how to use concat for values in the middle,

I have the following data

```
id,work_id,deptcd,"desc"
id,workcd,"desc"
```

and I want to change it to be like this

```
id,work_id,deptcd as code,"desc"
id,workcd as code,"desc"
```

I tried with a query like this, but the results did not match what I expected

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN columnmaster ILIKE '%cd%' THEN concat(columnmaster,' as code') ELSE columnmaster END AS code
,* FROM data
```

this is the result of my query

```
id,work_id,deptcd,"desc" as code
id,workcd,"desc" as code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
repcace(columnmaster, 'cd', 'cd as code')
```